# quotes and backslash in paste

Tags: r

I am using this in a loop:

```
xb=paste0(xb,ar,"==",dfp,'"',"&",'"')
```

where ar is "Male" and dfp is also "Male"
I want this to look like:

```
"Male"=="Male"&"Male"=="Male"&"Male=="Male"
```

after a few iterations of this line
But it looks like

```
"Male==Male\"&\"Male==Male\"&\"Male==Male\"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the loop:

```
xb=""
  numCol=c(2,3)
   for(ar in arguments){
     print(ar)
     for(i in numCol){
       print(i)
     for(dfp in dfparam[,i]){
       print(dfp)
       #browser()
       #xb=paste0(xb,ar,"==",dfp,'"',"&",'"')
       xb=cat(xb,'"',ar,'"=="',dfp,'"'," & ")
       #xb=cat(xb,ar,'"=="',dfp," & ")
     }
     }
   }
  print(xb)
```

with xb=cat(xb,'"',ar,'"=="',dfp,'"'," & "), I get this:

```
[1] "Male"
[1] 2
[1] "Male"
 " Male "==" Male "  & [1] "Male"
 " Male "==" Male "  & [1] "Male"
 " Male "==" Male "  & [1] "Male"
```

Comment: The backslashes are not part of the result string. They just escape the double quotes for printing purposes. Use `nchar` to see how many characters does the result have.

Comment: or use "cat" to print to screen

Comment: Your result is not what you expressed. See if this works better: `xb=paste0(xb,'"',ar,'"=="',dfp,'"'," & ")`. This will return: `"Male"=="Male" & "Male"=="Male" &` after two iterations.

Comment: thanks. tried: xb=paste0(xb,'"',ar,'"=="',dfp,'"'," & ")  but I get: "\"Male\"==\"Male\" & \"Male\"==\"Male\"

Comment: also tried:  xb=paste0(xb,ar,'"=="',dfp," & ")   and get: "Male\"==\"Male & Male\"==\"Male &  . When I try print(ar) I get  "Male"   .dfp is actually defined like this: dfp in dfparam[,i], and so it is a column but printing gives entries like "Male"

Comment: with  xb=cat(xb,'"',ar,'"=="',dfp,'"'," & ") ,I get this: [1] "Male"
[1] 2
[1] "Male"
 " Male "==" Male "  & [1] "Male"
 " Male "==" Male "  & [1] "Male"